# Add JavaScript in footer if shortcode used in page

Tags: shortcode, footer

I want to add javascript to page footer if the shortcode is used into the page content.

```
add_shortcode('show-popup', 'show_aip_popup');

function show_aip_popup($args){

   // HTML Comes here for popup
}
```

Comment: ok, what have you tried?

Comment: @Milo Thank you i have added short code and i have placed the [show-popup] in my page but there is problem with javascript jQuery load in footer and my shortcode js load into the page body so it give me error $ / jQuery not found

Comment: Please show us how your are enqueuing the Javascript in your shortcode callback.

Comment: @toscho I have do more google and i got the ans thank you for your time i am  going to add answer.

Comment: Well, but do not use more than one account for that!

Comment: @toscho i am not using more then one account i have only one account i have see one give the ans and its true so i have acceptd

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try this one

```
function show_aip_popup($args){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'parent-stylesheet', 'javascript file', false );
  //your code for show shortcode data
}
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your code. *Please try this one* is not a proper valid explanation to what your code does and how it works

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help

I have do some googling  and finally i got the ans i have added just 1 line of code into the shortcode function and i got the ans.

I have added bellow line into the shortcode function .

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'parent-stylesheet', '[js URL]' . $postId, false );
```

Comment: Hi @Mitul. Can you explain where you put this line in context of your other code? Thanks :)